# How to Unit Test View Model and Model of a Mvvm application in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Can you suggest me some resources on how to unit test viewmodel and model of a MVVM application.

I`ll be using rhino-mock as mock test framework.

Surprisingly, i cannot find any concrete resources.I have looked into
[MVC to unit test by Josh Smith](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23241/Using-MVC-to-Unit-Test-WPF-Applications)

but it did`nt helped me.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You may need to edit your question as it is currently [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)... *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing a ViewModel is not any different from testing regular classes. And that is the beauty of MVC. All you do in your view is call the methods.

Instead of looking for resources for writing unit test for MVC, I guess you should be looking for how to write testable code.

I would recommend you this link: http://www.netsoft-usa.com/2010/09/unit-testable-code-using-model-view-presenter/

Answer (score 2):

An example with [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net/) + [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) + [Fluent Assertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions).

As @Raghu already noted, there's no real difference from testing regular classes, but there may be some newer dimensions, such as how to test time-based effects. This may be answered by the Reactive Extensions approach by using a [Test Scheduler](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/03/10/master-time-with-reactive-extensions/).

In an example from my [blog](http://ledentsov.de/2014/07/26/reactiveui-viewmodel-testing/):

```
public class WordCounterViewModel : ReactiveObject {

 public WordCounterViewModel(IObservable<string> someBackgroundTicker)
 {
  ...
 }
...
}
```

And the test, including a dummy mock:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WordCounterViewModelTest()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IObservable<string>>();
    var vm = new WordCounterViewModel(mock.Object);

    vm.WordCount.Should().Be(0);

    vm.TextInput = "bla!";
    vm.WordCount.Should().Be(1);

    vm.TextInput = "bla, bla!!";
    vm.WordCount.Should().Be(2);
}
```

If you know how to create and run unit tests, you should be able to test your viewmodels now.